# How to set up LightGBM with GPU in a specific conda environment for Python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, conda, lightgbm

How can I install LightGBM module with the GPU support in a specific conda environment for Python?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this blog: https://www.thekerneltrip.com/machine-learning/lgbmgpu/

Answer (score 1):

For now only the https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/master/python-package/README.rst has actual receipt, e.g. for Ubuntu worked only the

```
pip install lightgbm --config-settings=cmake.define.USE_GPU=ON
```

inside a desired conda environment.

All the receipts that contains `setup.py` is now obsolete due to

> "...setup.py was removed from lightgbm as of v4.0.0."

as stated by developer in https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/issues/6240#issuecomment-1863900158

The https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html
is outdated.

So the only current way to obtain it is to

```
conda install <all other packages that you need in environment>
```

then activate it, then use the pip command above.

For non-linux platforms please consult on dependencies with the receipt in the first link.